# Auto sort list by column containing cells with formulas

Tags: excel, windows, vba

Need some VBA help, researched everywhere but no success. I have a list from A to G with 61 rows that needs to be automatically sorted by column G; problem is...the entries in column G are formulas based on the values of column E and F. I have the following code that does sort the list, but will do the automatic update as values change only if I click inside the formula and hit enter. The list refreshes and re-sorts then.

Here is my existing code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

  Range("A2:G61").Select 'this is the sort range
  Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
         OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  Target.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, as far as I was not able to get a lot from the explanation:

Would something like this work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'your code here
End Sub
```

What exactly is the problem? You do not want to click on the formulas every time?

Comment: yep that's correct, I just want the list to update automatically. columns E and F, used in the column G formula, feed from another system automatically. as a result, column G changes every say 10 seconds, and the sheet does not auto sort as the code above does not recognize the change in value (the formula stays the same). any thoughts? thanks so much for taking the time to look into it! Dee